# How to configure Ion cube license on localhost with Apache web server

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, xampp, ioncube

Client has given me a Ion Cube encoded PHP script to run on localhost. I have installed Ion Cube extension on web server successfully but ion cube did not decode the encoded files and show me a 500 internal error. When i reached to the client he asked me to configure the given license with localhost then Ion cube automatically decode the encoded files. Here is his response:

"Unfortunately I do not have access to the decrypted files. However the license.txt file included in project.7z should allow ionCube to automatically decode the files.
The server may need to be accessed though `localhost`".

Answer (score 0):

##### The *first thing* you need to check for error 500 is the *exact error description*. Unblock PHP error reporting, check log files (PHP, web server)

I'm not sure, but the code seems to be encoded for a specific php version. The version of the IonCube encoder may also be relevant.

The demo version of [this decoder](https://easytoyou.eu/decoders) should help you find the correct PHP version you need to install.

BTW: IonCube allows you to limit code execution on specific servers (ip / time-based licences)
More information can be found in the documentation: https://www.ioncube.com/sa/USER-GUIDE.pdf chapter 9